# Elasticsearch cannot query WKT

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, wkt

I'm retrieving geometry data from MS sql server 2012 via jdbc connection and pushing it to elasticsearch. Data table consist of: objectid & shape.
In Kibana data looks like following.

```
  "objectid": 8,
     "untitled": "POLYGON ((16131003.104400001 -4962095.885400001, 16131161.300499998 -4962011.5243000016, 16130990.071999997 -4961961.9569999985, 16131003.104400001 -4962095.885400001))",
```

The "Shape" field here apperes as "untitled" and on the mapping it shows data type as text,

```
 "untitled": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
```

I am querying the data from Kibana with following query and it prompts me the below error.

```
GET geo/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter" : {
                "geo_polygon" : {
                    "untitled" : {
                        "points" : [
                        {"lat" : 16131003.104400001, "lon" : -4962095.885400001},
                        {"lat" : 16131161.300499998, "lon" : -4962011.5243000016},
                        {"lat" : 16130990.071999997, "lon" : -4961961.9569999985},
                        {"lat" : 16131003.104400001, "lon" : -4962095.885400001}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "query_shard_exception",
        "reason": "field [untitled] is not a geo_point field",
        "index_uuid": "WEVvAQgASeap6n1eyOZ54g",
        "index": "geo"
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "geo",
        "node": "LuX-kU91RqqzKj-0DKFN6Q",
        "reason": {
          "type": "query_shard_exception",
          "reason": "field [untitled] is not a geo_point field",
          "index_uuid": "WEVvAQgASeap6n1eyOZ54g",
          "index": "geo"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Would be really appreciate if any one could help me out with this.

ps. I'm super new to elasticsearch and sorry for any stupid question :(

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the mapping of your field `untitled` to be a [geo shape](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/geo-shape.html).

Then you should be able to use a [geo shape query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/query-dsl-geo-shape-query.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @dadoonet

In https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/geo-shape.html, it states that elastic support WKT.
Is there anyway I can mutate the type or convert the WKT to geo_shape?

Comment: You need to reindex